# Can you hide tables from a MySQL user in phpMyAdmin?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a MySQL user added to a database that I would like to prevent from viewing certain tables.

I can limit their privileges through MySQL by preventing them from running statements like DROP or ALTER.  But is it possible to prevent them from viewing certain tables in phpMyAdmin?

If there isn't a MySQL privilege that controls this (I wouldn't imagine there would be), is there a configuration in phpMyAdmin that allows this?

I understand one workaround here is to move the tables to a new database that they're not added to.  This isn't an option for my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could move the tables to another database and then restrict the user account to only access the 1 database with the public tables.   Trying to modify phpmyadmin would be a massive mistake, the user could just write a custom query to access the tables,  thats a dead simple hack.

This has to be done on the database side or there is absolutely no point.  [SE-Postgresql](http://code.google.com/p/sepgsql/) is the only project i know of that allows for table by table permissions.  This is the only database that can do this because **very** few people need this feature.

Comment: MySQL/phpMyAdmin has table by table permissions. You could set it up such that the user couldn't select from the table. The only way to prevent the user from knowing the table exists is to put said table in a database the user can't access, as Rook said.

Comment: Furthermore, you could prevent users from executing SQL queries in PhpMyAdmin and block access to the server from outside connections. There is no real reason why this can't be done in the way PhpMyAdmin implements the design tools and extras.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can hide a particular database in phpmyadmin.
In order to do that, just open **config.inc.php** in your **phpmyadmin** directory in your webserver root or where it is placed. or search for **config.inc.php**
if you want to hide *information_schema* and *mysql* add this line after:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysql';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['hide_db'] = '^information_schema|mysql$';
```

This is It.

Answer (score 0):

phpMyAdmin connects to the database as a certain MySQL user. If that user does not have any permissions on the given tables no phpMyAdmin user can access that. That would hold for *all* mypMyAdmin users of course.